# Why I can't run a python.exe in another computer with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller, glob, python-tesseract

I have created a python.exe file with pyinstaller. In my computer the program works as I want. The problem is when I move it to another computer the program just open the console and dont do that I want. I mean, open the console and close at the same time. In the code below, I open some files where the path is give it for the user. I dont know if the problem is that or the problem is in the library that I import. Also, I dont have installed python in the another computer, does it matter?

I will leave the "main" function, the other functions are not important

I think the problem its in the first line of code when I get the files in the list.

I will be thankful if someone realize of the error
Thank you in advance

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import glob
import random
import time


path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract


path = input("Ingresa la direccion: ")
final_path = path + "\*.PNG"



def get_lists():
    list_images = glob.glob(final_path)
    legendary = []
    shiny = []
    fourstars = []
    rest = []
    for image in list_images:
        text = get_text(image)
        order_images(image, text, legendary, shiny, fourstars, rest)

    return legendary, shiny, fourstars, rest
```

Comment: I don't believe that this runs: you never call the function.

Comment: This is not the complete code, it's just the function where I think it's the error

Comment: Are you sure that the hardcoded `path_to_tesseract` is correct on the machine?

Comment: Oh, yes, I think this is the problem. Do you know how I could "export" the library into the .exe file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @lit  This was the problem. I have spent hours trying to find the error. Thank you so much!!